# ¿Cómo obtener los tres primeros caracteres de una palabra?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Realizo un pequeño formulario el cual tiene dos campos de texto, en uno el usuario podrá escribir y en el otro mostrará los tres primeros caracteres de cada palabra (Si son dos palabras = 6 caracteres, tres palabras = 9 caracteres y así sucesivamente.

**Condiciones:** Después de cada espacio se reinicia un contador para una palabra nueva.

**Formulario**

```
 private void txtWordsKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    txtShort.setText(Filtro.getCurrentInstance().filter(txtWords.getText()));
}
```

**Clase Filtro**

```
public class Filtro{
private static Filtro _filter = null;
int count = 0;

private Filtro(){

}

public static synchronized Filtro getCurrentInstance(){
    if(_filter == null){
        _filter = new Filtro();
    }
    return _filter;
}

public String filter(String word) {
    String almacen = "";


    char[] letters = word.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {         

        if (count == 3) {

            if (letters[i] == ' ') {
                count = 0;
            }
        }else{

            if (letters[i] == ' ') {
                count = 0;
            }else{
                almacen += letters[i];
                count++;

            }
        }
    }
    return almacen;
}
```

La problemática es que no puedo hacer que funcione de manera correcta.

Comment: Y si la palabra tiene menos de 3 caracteres?

Comment: Creo que no haría nada. Suponiendo que la palabra solo tuviera dos letras las almacenará y estaría esperando un tercer carácter. Si solo tuviera las dos letras, un espacio y una palabra, en teoría almacenará los dos caracteres de la primera, reiniciará el contador por el espacio que habría y empezará a almacenar los caracteres de la palabra nueva. No se si me explique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementación del método `filter()`

```
public String filter(String word) {

     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // Se crea un arreglo que contiene todas las palabras
    String palabras[] = word.split(" ");

        //Se recorren todas las palabras del arreglo
        for (String palabra : palabras) {
         //si la longitud de la palabra es igual o mayor a 3 caracteres 
         //se extraen los primeros 3
            if (palabra.length() >= 3) {
                builder.append(palabra.substring(0, 3));
            } else {
         //si la longitud es menor a 3 se agrega la palagra completa
                builder.append(palabra);
            }
        }
      //se retorna el string formado por las iniciales
      return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Cual es la función del StringBuilder?

Comment: StringBuilder se usa para trabajar con cadenas de caracteres mutables. Los objetos de la clase String son inmutables y por cada modificación que se haga se crea un nuevo objeto, en cambio StringBuilder permite crear cadenas de texto que se pueden manipular sin crear objetos nuevos.

Comment: Probare el código